# how to convert array of numbers to dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying the following code:

```
dict=deliveryDays.split(";").map((item,i)=>{
    return ({ i :item})
});
```

deliveryDays is an array of numbers but i inside the { i :item} is not the i passing in the map.
what I want is:

```
[{0:"1", 1:"1", 2:"1" }]
```

but what I see is:

```
[{"i":"0"},{"i":"1"},{"i":"1"}]
```

So as you can see the i does not get the right value of i.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to spread your array inside a new object. I don't see the point of have an array including only one object based on your expected output: `[{0:"1", 1:"1", 2:"1" }]`. So my first guess will be that you need this::

```js
let deliveryDays = "1;2;3;4;5"
let obj = {...deliveryDays.split(";")};
console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

If you still need the only object inside an array, then is easy to figure out that next code will do it:

```
let obj = [{...deliveryDays.split(";")}];
```

In the other hand, if you want an array with multiple objects, then you can do this:

```js
let deliveryDays = "1;2;3;4;5"
let res = deliveryDays.split(";").map((x, idx) => ({[idx]: x}));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: You are getting an `object` and i think the OP want an `array`

Comment: @YosvelQuintero the OP says he wanted this: `[{0:"1", 1:"1", 2:"1" }]`, I have clarifyed that for me it has no sense to have only one object inside an array. But I have included the alternative just in case.

Comment: Good response.. I was having a bad understanding and updated my answer.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the `[]` bracket notation to evaluate the value of `i`. So in your case it is not evaluated but simply outputs `"i"` as a string in the key of the object.

```js
const deliveryDays = "1;2;3;4";
const dict = deliveryDays.split(";").map((item,i)=> ({[i]:item}));
console.log(dict);
```

But I believe you want it as a single object wrapped in an array which can be done using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const deliveryDays = "1;2;3;4";
const dict = deliveryDays.split(";").reduce((acc,item,i)=>{
  acc[i] = item;
  return acc;
},{});
console.log([dict]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const deliveryDays = '1;2;3;4;5;6';
const dict = [Object.assign({}, deliveryDays.split(';'))];

console.log(dict);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spread Syntax

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 1];
let result = [{...arr}]
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way is to use [**Object.entries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const deliveryDays = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const dict = Object.entries(deliveryDays).map(([key,value])=>({[key]:value}))

console.log(dict);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```